# Filter functionality in tableview

Tags: javafx

I am currently testing out tableview in JavaFX. Is there any way where I can add a empty row on top for filtering like in the image underneath(print screen from Microsoft AX)? The empty row marked with yellow is purely used for filtering, and if you write in any of the columns it will filter by that.

[image: ttp://www.asisucceed.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/TipsTools_Ax_4.jpg]

Comment: You can use a CellFactory to achieve this !

Comment: Would you care to elaborate?